# How do I remove a virus that ClamAV has found?

Tags: clamav

I recently ran a virus check using clam av, and the result was 1 infected file found, can anybody please help me remove/fix this.

Swf.Exploit.CVE_2015_5123-1

Comment: Which is the infected file?

Comment: /home/tony/.cache/opera/Cache/f_005fb6

Comment: On an unrelated note, how do you like ClamAV? I just got a fresh install of Ubuntu server done and am wondering which anti-virus to use because it'll be used as a Windows share so I'll need to be able to check for Windows and Linux viruses.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2015-5123/. Run `rm /home/tony/.cache/opera/Cache/f_005fb6` then clear the Cache in opera settings. No guarantee there are not more on your system. My advice is to switch to a flash-less browser like chromium. Flash is full of bugs that will never be fixed and most things work without it now. If you need flash you can always use a virtual machine to be secure.

Comment: No problem hope it helps. Unfortunately some websites still haven't gone to HTML5 video but most have and flash is deprecated so never going to fix all the wholes.